# Rounding a timestamp to hourly interval?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a field called time below:

```
    time
2019-12-03 14:45:11
2019-12-03 03:58:45
2019-11-03 10:03:03
```

Can I select the time column but round each timestamp down to that hours interval?

Output:

```
 time
2019-12-03 14:00:00
2019-12-03 03:00:00
2019-11-03 10:00:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`DATE_TRUNC`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) function with `HOUR` as the date/time part:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', time)
FROM yourTable;
```